# Trimming a long text to get what I want using substring

Tags: c#, uwp, arcgis, projection, esri

I have a program that was created using c# in UWP and we have a map embedded in it using ESRI.ArcGISRuntime libraries.

I want to show the datum only and I have used substring to extract what I need but it always gives me to much.

This is the line of code I get:

PROJCS[“WGS_84_Web_Mercator_auxillary_Sphere”.DATUM[“GCS WGS 1984”.SPHEROID[“WGS 1984”.6378………..

I want to show only what is after DATUM and before SPHEROID, which is GCS WGS 1984.

This is what I have so far:

```
_currentProjection = _tileLayer.SpatialReference.WkText.Substring(_tileLayer.SpatialReference.WkText.LastIndexOf("DATUM") + 9, _tileLayer.SpatialReference.WkText.StartsWith.ToString("SPHEROID");
```

The first part of the substring is correct, but I cannot get the second part correct.  Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty of ways but Regex would probably be my candidate of choice

```
var code = @"PROJCS[""WGS_84_Web_Mercator_auxillary_Sphere"".DATUM[""GCS WGS 1984"".SPHEROID[""WGS 1984"".637";

var m = Regex.Match(code, @"DATUM\[""(?<d>[A-Z0-9 ]+)""\.SPHEROID"); 
var r = m.Groups["d"].Value;
```

If you want to do it as substring:

```
var code = @"PROJCS[""WGS_84_Web_Mercator_auxillary_Sphere"".DATUM[""GCS WGS 1984"".SPHEROID[""WGS 1984"".637";

var f = code.IndexOf("DATUM") + 7;
var t = code.IndexOf("SPHEROID") - 2;
var r = code[f..t]; //this is C#9 indexes and ranges; if you don't have it you can upgrade C# or use .Substring(f, t-f)
```

Or Split:

```
var code = @"PROJCS[""WGS_84_Web_Mercator_auxillary_Sphere"".DATUM[""GCS WGS 1984"".SPHEROID[""WGS 1984"".637";

var bits = code.Split('"');
var i = Array.FindIndex(bits, b => b.Contains("DATUM"));
var r = bits[i+1];
```

Comment: Ok I will give this a shot.  Thank you!!

Comment: I tried both, the first option you wrote gave me nothing (I want to write it on the screen as text) and the second one gave me lots of characters after the word SPHEROID.

Comment: First works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OqyyoU

Comment: Second works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eb2pBt

Comment: Third works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BsaDxS

Comment: Note that for the first and third, I assumed that the curly quotes in the question text were a bad paste so they were swapped for straight quotes. If the data truly has curly quotes in it you'll need to adjust the regular expression pattern to be `@"DATUM\[“(?<d>[A-Z0-9 ]+)”\.SPHEROID"` or in the third case `.Split('“', '”')`

Comment: Yes i got it to work, thank you Caius!!